# Matlab: str2double works on Windows PC but not on Apple Mac

Tags: matlab

Say I have the following example file names: file_0250.pdf, file_0251.pdf, file_0252.pdf. I would like to get the following cell array:

```
'250 251 252'.
```

On the Windows PC at work I can run the following code with no problems, but on my Macbook at home I can not get the 'str2double' values as it returns a NaN value. It's frustrating:

```
folder_name = '/User/....';
file_name = 'file_';
extension = '.pdf';

 %//' files pattern with absolute paths
filePattern = fullfile(folder_name, [file_name '*' extension] ); 


old_filename = cellstr(ls(filePattern)) ;

%// Get numbers associated with each file
file_ID = strrep(strrep(old_filename, file_name ,''), extension,'');

file_ID_doublearr = str2double(file_ID);
```

I tried 'cell2mat', 'str2mat', but they do not go well with the rest of the code:

```
file_ID_doublearr = file_ID_doublearr - min(file_ID_doublearr)+ start_number;

file_ID = strtrim(cellstr(num2str(file_ID_doublearr)));

%// Get zeros string to be pre-appended to each new_name
str_zeros = arrayfun(@(t) repmat('0',1,t), 4-cellfun(@numel,file_ID),'uni',0) ;

%// Generate new filenames
new_name = get(handles.new_name, 'string');
new_extension = get(handles.new_extension, 'string');

new_filename = strcat(new_name,str_zeros,file_ID,new_extension) ;

%// Finally rename files with the absolute paths
cellfun(@(m1,m2) movefile(m1,m2),fullfile(folder_name,file_name),fullfile(folder_name,new_filename)) ;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue has to do with the different way that *nix (Linux and Mac) and Windows treat `ls` [as mentioned in the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ls.html#outputarg_list). As you've found out, `ls` returns a 2D character array of filenames. On the PC, these filenames will be returned one per row.

```
file_001.pdf
file_002.pdf
file_003.pdf
file_004.pdf
```

When you call `cellstr` on the result, it will place each filename into it's own cell array element after which you can successfully extract the number portion and convert them to numbers.

On *nix-based systems though, `ls` will typically yield a *multi-column* output. For example:

```
file_001.pdf    file_002.pdf    file_003.pdf
file_004.pdf
```

When you call `cellstr` on this, you will get one cell array element *per row*, but as you can see the first row actually contains *three* filenames. Then once you extract the number portion you would get something like this:

```
'001 002 003'
'004'
```

When you try to convert to a number, you're trying to convert a string of numbers to a single number and you get a `NaN`.

```
str2double({'001 002 003'; '004'})
%   NaN   4
```

The *best* way to fix this is to *not* use the OS-dependent `ls` and use [`dir`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dir.html) instead which is guaranteed to have consistent behavior across operating systems.

```
files = dir(fullfile(folder_name, [filename, '*', extension]));
numbers = regexp({files.name}, '[0-9]*', 'match');
```

The other option is to make sure that `file_ID` does not contain any space-separated numbers.

```
file_IDs = {'001 002 003'; '004'};

% Break each element up into multiple elements if it contains spaces
file_IDs = cellfun(@(x)strsplit(x), file_IDs, 'UniformOutput', 0);
file_IDs = cat(2, file_IDs{:});

% Now convert to a number
str2double(file_IDs);
%   1  2  3  4
```

Comment: @Mosawi The problem is *not* with `str2double` it is with using `ls`. I have added more of an explanation to my answer.